# How can I find the process template of my TFS Project

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to see what Template my TFS Project is using?

Ie Scrum for Team System, MSFT Agile 4 etc....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That information is not stored in your TFS environment. The only thing you can do is to look at the work item types or the states in the work item and 'guess' which template it is.

For example: in TFS 2008, the Agile has a Scenario, while the CMMI has a Requirement. 
In TFS 2010, the Agile has a User Story, while the CMMI has a Requirement.

Comment: Is this answer wrong? It conflicts with your answer, I believe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909223/how-to-determine-used-process-template-in-team-foundation-server-after-creation

Comment: See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dstfs/archive/2013/09/27/determining-process-template-of-an-existing-team-project-in-tfs-2012.aspx

Answer (score 7):

In TFS 2010, you can right-click on a project and select "Team Project Process Guidance". This will prompt you to save a html page and then prompt you to open it. When the page opens, it will be a MSDN page containing information about the process template thats used for the team project.

E.g if you had created a team project with CMMi v5.0 process template, then you will get the MSDN page for CMMi v5.0, if it was created with Agile 5.0, then you will get the MSDN page for Agile v5.0.

This way, you can identify which process template your project is based on.

Hope this is helpful.( after nearly 1 and half years of the initial post, I am not sure but might be to other users ).

Regards,
Kuraish.

Comment: Note that this is only applicable if Process Guidance is already enabled. In my case it is not. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242876%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#DeterminingProcessGuidance)

Comment: This is also available in TFS 2008.  But instead of right-clicking on the team project, you need to right-click on the Work Items folder.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the workflow states of a task in your project portal you can easily say which procress template a TFS project belongs to.

For scrum: workflow states are: New, Approved, Committed, Done, Removed

For agile: New, Active, Resolved, Closed, Removed

For CMMI: Proposed,Active,Resolved,Closed

More differences between process templates can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms400752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Hope this helps.