# I have existing team project ( TFS 2018 )I want to know which process template have been used

Tags: tfs

I have existing team project ( TFS 2018 )I want to know  which process template have been used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine used process template in Team Foundation Server after creation of team project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909223/how-to-determine-used-process-template-in-team-foundation-server-after-creation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use 1 from 3 built-in templates (Agile, Scrum, CMMI) you can check which work item type you have:

- Agile - User story
- Scrum - Product Backlog Item
- CMMI - Requirement

If you use a custom template you can check the process template with rest API:

```
Get http://yourServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/TestTemplate?includeCapabilities=true&api-version=1.0
```

You could get the result about the template like the following:

```
"capabilities": {
"processTemplate": {
  "templateName": "Test"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

1. List the projects via REST API and get the `{projectId}` for
   a specific project:

   ```
   GET http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects
   ```
2. Retrieve the Process template information from project
   properties by calling REST API:

   ```
   GET http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/{projectId}/properties
   ```

   Please see [Projects - Get Project Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/core/projects/get%20project%20properties?view=vsts-rest-4.1) for details.

Well, you can simply use below Powershell script to get which process template have been used for a specific team project:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",
   [string]$projectname = "GXJGitTest",
   [string]$user = "domain\user",
   [string]$token = "password/PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get project ID
$ProjectsUrl = "$collectionurl/_apis/projects"          
$ProjectsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ProjectsUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$projectid = ($ProjectsResponse.value | where {$_.name -eq $projectname}).id

#Get system.template  
$PTurl = "$collectionurl/_apis/projects/$projectid/properties"      
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PTurl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$ProcressTemplate = ($response.value | where {$_.name -eq 'System.Process Template'}).value 

Clear-host
Write-Host "The project $projectname is using the $ProcressTemplate Process Template."
```

[image]